# How do I set request path parameters in the generated SDK for my AWS API Gateway

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

How do I set the request path parameters in the API Gateway SDK I created?

I have a PUT request like this: `/users/{id}`

It works great when I test it in the API Gateway GUI. I am asked to provide the ID parameter.

But when I create the SDK I get the following method (Android/Java):

```
@Operation(
    path = "/users/{id}",
    method = "PUT"
)
void usersIdPut(UserPut var1);
```

There is no way I can change the path. It will call the URL with `{id}` literally in it.

I have tried to put ID in the UserPut model but no difference.

How do I do this?

Comment: You can export the REST API in openapi/swagger spec and then use [swagger codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) to generate the android API clients. Pls refer to https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-generate-an-android-sdk for more info.

Comment: It should handle this case, let me take a look and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce the issue, I have a request model, response model, and one path param on the method and I get this from SDK client:

```
    @Operation(
        path = "/mappingtest/{id}",
        method = "GET"
    )
    Empty mappingtestIdGet(@Parameter(
    name = "id",
    location = "path"
) String var1, Empty var2);
```

Could you check to make sure the parameter is defined in the 'Request Paths' section on Method Request? And also that you've deployed the latest changes because the SDK's are build off of the deployed stages.

Comment: I will double check. It is possible that I have made an error. I will be back.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and it turns out the issue was I was using the Serverless framework, and it wasn't setting the "requestParameter" field to mark the path parameter. e.g. `{"method.request.path.id": true}`

From the documentation
(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/put-method.html):

> requestParameters -> (map)
>   A key-value map defining required or optional method request parameters that can be accepted by Amazon API Gateway. A key is a method request parameter name matching the pattern of method.request.{location}.{name} , where location is querystring , path , or header and name is a valid and unique parameter name. The value associated with the key is a api-key-required flag indicating whether the parameter is required (true ) or optional (false ). The method request parameter names defined here are available in Integration to be mapped to integration request parameters or templates.

I was able to get it working after installing the serverless framework from the github source instead of the release, which added [support](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/commit/1b1ce334e7962be93d395d45d6e722db55a433df#diff-00379095eed199037d59a19747422167) for the request parameter field recently